# What means that "Nail"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

What does *nail* mean in the below sentence? ( Here C# is a programming language)

> Nail Your C# Developer Interview.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94841/what-does-nailed-it-mean

Comment: related:[The meaning of nailed in the conversation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159272/the-meaning-of-nailed-in-the-conversation) and [“Screwed” vs. “nailed”: why is the slang so different?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124801/screwed-vs-nailed-why-is-the-slang-so-different)

Answer (score 1):

"Nail" can be used to mean many different things. The slang meaning implied in this sentence is:

> - to perform a task excellently.

(from [OnlineSlangDictionary.com](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/nail))

Answer (score 0):

'To nail something' means to be successful in something, or to achieve something, so here it means 'Succeed in your C# Developer Interview'